# Using aggregates with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

- ideas
- votes
- comments

My goal is to extract

1. Basic data from ideas such as "content" and "title"
2. Sum of votes for that idea
3. Number of comments on the idea

The problem is that when i use two LEFT JOINS (one on comment and one on votes) i end upp with duplicate rows and the sum over votes is incorrect. That is:

```
SELECT ideas.*, 
       vote, 
       comments.id 
FROM   ideas 
       LEFT JOIN votes 
              ON ideas.id = votes.idea_id 
       LEFT JOIN comments 
              ON ideas.id = comments.idea_id
```

Will generate multiple rows for each vote, rendering a sum(votes) useless.

[**EDIT:**]
Hence the following query will fail to get the correct sum of votes:

```
SELECT ideas.*, 
       sum(votes.vote), 
       count(comments.id)
FROM ideas
    LEFT JOIN votes 
        ON ideas.id = votes.idea_id 
    LEFT JOIN comments 
        ON ideas.id = comments.idea_id
GROUP BY votes.id
```

Comment: "fake rows" you mean duplicating ?

Comment: can u update your post with a sqlfiddle.com link with sample data

Comment: See my answer here: **[Help with this query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/help-with-this-query/17016#17016)**

Comment: It's unclear what you want to return.. Returning the total number of votes on an idea, as well as all comments on that idea probably shouldn't be done in the same query

Comment: @ypercube, thank you i believe this is exactly what im looking for! Great with the alternatives.

Comment: If you want to use `SUM(votes.vote)`, then go for option 1 or 3 (I don't think option 2 will work correctly with SUM.)